# Debugging application in Blackberry device

Tags: blackberry

I am facing problem while debugging my application in blackberry device, I am able to run my application successfully in simulator.

When I right click my application and click as debug as -> Blackberry device, I get one pop up asking for Signing password(minimum 8 characters) and I enter my password which i was given.

After this signature tool starts automatically and try to send request for RRT,RBB,RCR but every time its fail.When I try to open my application icon in device it says "APPLICATIONNAME attempts to access a secure API".

In mean while when signature tool is running I get one message in details part that "Code file does not contain a signature from this SignerID.  Please request a signature." and when signature tool complete its execution I get message in detail that "General failure.  Please try again. Server may be unavailable."

I am able to debug my simple generated application in device(which do not include any secure api).Also, same key is working fine in other pc(I am able to debug application in device from other pc using same key and procedure).

This is very first time I am trying to debug(run) my application in blackberry device so it might be possible that I am missing any/some important part, If so kindly tell me where I am going wrong.I am using Blackberry Java plugin for eclipse and Blackberry device manager.

Answer (score 1):

every plugin requires separate keys.Once used keys will not works for other plugin ....u have to signin in with other new keys.

Comment: Actually, you should be able to reuse the keys.  Under the **BlackBerry** menu, you can select **Sign** -> **Import Existing Keys**. I use the same code signing keys on multiple PCs.

Answer (score 0):

Please following following step.
1. First signature application.
2. Install signed application on blackberry device.
3. on eclipse simulator Right click on project and "Debug As ->Blackberry Device".

Now you application already sign then there are no chance to ask signature password. And message display that already signed. please close that windows.

Now debug begin on blackberry device.